# why $app-direction: rtl not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/rtl-support/

I wonder why this variable `$app-direction: rtl;` in `/src/theme/variables.scss` not working / have no effect ?

```
ionic --version
3.6.0
```

The UI is the same, with or without it.

According to the docs, they state that $app-direction is set somewhere in the `./node_modules/ionic-angular/themes/ionic.globals.scss` file. at least for me - there's no such variable ... and as far as I'm aware - I'm using the latest version no ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, that `$app-direction: rtl;` should be placed in the `variables.scss` file, and the only thing that variable does is

> To enable support for RTL language

and

> This has the added benefit of also keeping the generated CSS a bit smaller as well.

**But it doesn't make your app RTL.** If you want to change the layout of your app to make it RTL, just like you can see [in the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#setDir):

> **We recommend the app’s index.html file already has the correct dir
>   attribute value set, such as `<html dir="ltr">` or `<html dir="rtl">`.**

If in your scenario you need to change it dynamically, you can use the `setDir(dir, updateDocument)` method from the `Platform`, like this:

```
private setProperAligment(): void {

    if (this.selectedLanguage.rtl) {
        this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
        // ...
    } else {
        this.platform.setDir('ltr', true);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be an issue with that specific component (RTL is still being improved and worked on right now). But if you see that the overall alignment has changed, then your RTL configuration is working properly

Comment: mmm yes it it - I see that my nav items, actually changed - thank you very much !

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: searchbar and ion-input not change direction. I check in dom, showing dir="auto".